# Missing Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I upload all my cakephp project files in live but give error
    message

```
 message is:

 Error: Table billboards for model Billboard was not found in
datasource default.
```

error image is :

[image]

database table name is : billboards

```
Model name is : Billboard.php

<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class Billboard extends AppModel {

   var $name = "billboards";

}

?>

Now what is my Mistakes?
```

Comment: Well, i think this is pretty obvious. In your live database, do you that table billboards?

Comment: yes database table name is : billboards

Comment: delete all your cache files and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is now solve.
I flow some step

1. Check all cakephp convention.
2. All file delete from live.
3. Again upload all file in live.
4. Then I saw every thing is ok.